# How to define a class attribute by other attributes of the same class using "attrs"

Tags: python, python-dataclasses, python-attrs

I'm new with `attrs` module & I've encountered something that I didn't understand very well.
For simplicity I have this code below:

```
import attr
from typing import List

@attr.define
class A:
    a: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='hi')
    b: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='bye')
    ab: List[str] = attr.ib(init=False, default=[a, b])


def main() -> None:
    a = A()
    print(a.a)
    print(a.b)
    print(a.ab)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

But while I expected to get the output:

```
hi
bye
["hi", "bye"]
```

As a beginner, The output I get is a bit strange to me:

```
hi
bye
[_CountingAttr(counter=18, _default='hi', repr=True, eq=True, order=True, hash=None, init=False, on_setattr=None, metadata={}), _CountingAttr(counter=19, _default='bye', repr=True, eq=True, order=True, hash=None, init=False, on_setattr=None, metadata={})]
```

I'll appreciate any explanation to understand the reason & how I can handle it.

Comment: Inside the class scope, ``a`` and ``b`` are literally ``attr.ib`` placeholders, not their defaults. So ``[a, b]`` is a list of the placeholders; ``attrs`` doesn't know that you expect it to peek arbitrarily deep into the default and pick out placeholders there.

Comment: @MisterMiyagi is there a way to access the default value manually from inside the class?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

At class definition time. `a` and `b` are just the result of `attr.ib(...)`. And if somehow that worked, `default=[a, b]` means to give this reference to every object that this class creates. Meaning that every `A` you create would reference the same list.

What you want to do it's to use `attr.ib(factory=list)` when you want a new list for every object. `factory=list` it's just an alias to `default=attr.Factory(list)`. `attr.Factory` has this keyword `takes_self` that can enhance this functionality further. So you can use `attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(lambda self: [self.a, self.b], takes_self=True))` to do what you want.

```py
n [2]: import attr
   ...: from typing import List
   ...: 
   ...: @attr.define
   ...: class A:
   ...:     a: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='hi')
   ...:     b: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='bye')
   ...:     ab: List[str] = attr.ib(default=attr.Factory(lambda self: [self.a, self.b], takes_self=True))
   ...: 
   ...: def main() -> None:
   ...:     a = A()
   ...:     print(a.a)
   ...:     print(a.b)
   ...:     print(a.ab)
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: if __name__ == '__main__':
   ...:     main()
   ...: 
hi
bye
['hi', 'bye']
```

If you need to do something more complex or dislike lambdas, you can also use:

```py
In [3]: import attr
   ...: from typing import List
   ...: 
   ...: @attr.define
   ...: class A:
   ...:     a: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='hi')
   ...:     b: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='bye')
   ...:     ab: List[str] = attr.ib()
   ...: 
   ...:     @ab.default
   ...:     def _(self):
   ...:         return [self.a, self.b]
   ...: 
   ...: def main() -> None:
   ...:     a = A()
   ...:     print(a.a)
   ...:     print(a.b)
   ...:     print(a.ab)
   ...: 
   ...: 
   ...: if __name__ == '__main__':
   ...:     main()
   ...: 
hi
bye
['hi', 'bye']
```

Answer (score 0):

I have found the solution in [attrs.org](https://www.attrs.org/en/stable/examples.html#immutability)

`attrs` module has a post `__init__` magic function: `__attrs_post_init__` exactly for cases like mine that I described in my question.

That's the solution, post it here for others who will encounter the same question like me:

```
import attr
from typing import List

@attr.define
class A:
    a: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='hi')
    b: str = attr.ib(init=False, default='bye')
    ab: List[str] = attr.ib(default=[])

    def __attrs_post_init__(self):
        self.ab = [self.a, self.b]


def main() -> None:
    a = A()
    print(a.a)
    print(a.b)
    print(a.ab)


if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

Comment: That works, but it sets the `ab` value twice and discards the first value, which is unnecessary. Also, it's not recommended to use mutable defaults.